# Using dplyr group_by corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

I tried to replicate this approach to find the means for different groups in my dataset: [Means multiple columns by multiple groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330352/means-multiple-columns-by-multiple-groups) and the following code:

```
newtest %>%
  group_by(aligntool, paired) %>%
  summarise(vars("read_per_length"), mean)
```

However, I get the following error message:

> ```
> In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
>   corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
> ```

I tested to see if this was a problem with zero values, so I removed those and got the same problem. I also made the dataset smaller to see if this was a memory issue. For reference, my dataframe looks like this:

```
str(newtest)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Run_Sample     : Factor w/ 6 levels "Run_1768_Sample_77304",..: 5 6 3 3 4 6 2 1 6 6 ...
 $ paired         : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ aligntool      : Factor w/ 2 levels "bbmap","kallisto": 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ read_per_length: num  2.60e-10 1.87e-09 3.28e-09 7.63e-10 1.38e-09 ...
```

Is there a problem in how my dataframe is formatted somehow? How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Use `summarize_at()` instead of `summarize()`.

Comment: @OTStats - I suspect that others may also make this same mistake and could benefit from it being answered here.  Perhaps consider making your comment into an answer?

Comment: @dww I'm not sure it works, hoping will try it.

Comment: My other problem was how I installed packages. I individually installed dplyr/tidyr instead of     'install.packages("tidyverse")' This solved some dependency issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
newtest %>%
  group_by(aligntool, paired) %>%
  summarise_at(vars("read_per_length"), mean)
```